# Highlight some text and replace with what's in clipboard

Tags: vim

I made a copy of a file and need to update a path within that file.

In it's current state the line in question looks like this:

```
0 8 1 * * /home/apples/pears/carrots.sh > /home/apples/pears/blah.log 2>&1
```

I'd like to replace `/home/apples/pears/carrots.sh` with `/home/bananas/nuts/yams.sh`

I copied /home/bananas/nuts/yams.sh just with command + c. Then, with the file open in vim I entered visual mode at the beginning of /home and using `e`  ensured the text to be replaced was highted all the way to the end of the directory path.

I then hit `r`  to replace and then typed `p`  for paste/put but instead the entire path is now one long list of p's!

How can I highlight some text and replace it with whats in my clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` by definition does this. From `:h v_r`:

```
{Visual}["x]r{char} Replace all selected characters by {char}.
```

You can simply paste/put over the visually selected text to replace it.

```
vE"+p
```

Note: I am use `"+` register as that is my system's clipboard. Change as needed.

For more help see:

```
:h v_r
:h quoteplus
:h v_p
:h E
:h word
:h WORD
```